# Silent push notification and background task

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, background, scheduled-tasks

I found out that from the server I can send a silent notification to the user.This notification wakes up the application and gives 30 seconds to run in the background.

After receiving such a notification, ***can I start sending the user's current location to the server every 15 minutes?***
I will do this using a plugin (cordova - BackgroundFetch)

***Or will all processes be terminated after 30 seconds?***

Answer (score 0):

I've never implemented using cordova, but have worked extensively on an application that implements background tasks, so location.

You can refer to this answer, it is little old but I think can give you a north.

[What strategy to adopt to monitor the user location in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147002/what-strategy-to-adopt-to-monitor-the-user-location-in-background/45152418#45152418)

You can add the silent notification as a plus to start the process up to your need.